# IE11 HTML5 Won't Play MP3 File

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio

I have a simple sound clip that I would like to play. I am using the code:

```
var snd = new Audio("https://mobile-text-alerts.com/3.0/system/nexmo/messages/1404764969.mp3");
snd.play();
```

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but I cannot get it to work in Internet Explorer (11 in particular). I originally was trying to get a .wav to play, but I later came to find out IE11 doesn't support playing wav files. But now I have made it an mp3, and it still can't play it.

I tried messing with my .htaccess file by adding `AddType audio/mpeg .mp3`, I also tried `AddType audio/mp3 .mp3` and anything else I could think of, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see anything printing in your console?

Comment: I get [`MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-mediaerror-media_err_src_not_supported)

Comment: Is this happening in all versions of IE? I would add the following to your <head> tags and test it again: `<meta http-equiv-"X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your file is not an MP3 file, but a WAV file with the MP3 file extension. Here is the output from the *nix file command to confirm this.

> 1404764969.mp3: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000 Hz

This is the reason you are getting the `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED` error. You will need to properly transcode your file to MP3. Just changing the file extension will not work.